# error message " Mailing to remote domains not supported" in mutt how to fix

Tags: mutt

How can I set up any command line mail agent to deliver to gmail accounts?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the text of this error might originate from `exim4` in Debian:

```
# fgrep remote /var/log/exim4/mainlog.1 | sed -E 's#([ <])[^ <]+@[^ >]+([ >])#\1a@b\2#g' | head -1
2019-01-08 00:47:00 1ggebk-00055M-St ** a@b <a@b> R=nonlocal: Mailing to remote domains not supported
#
```

It would appear that the solution would be to reconfigure `exim4`, and within the initial `ncurses` dialogue, make sure to select the ***`internet site; mail is sent and received directly using SMTP`*** option (in place of what is probably, the `local delivery only; not on a network` option):

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

Note that although the top option implies that mail from the internet would now be accepted, it would appear that even if selected, by default it's still limited to the localhost IPv4/IPv6 addresses for accepting the mail (if you leave the defaults in subsequent prompts of the reconfig), so, it would seem that you don't really have to worry about having the `smtp` port open on the server to the outside world just by selecting the top-level option (TBH, it then makes little sense why it's not even the default, as sending mail to the outside world is a pretty common operation that generally works without any extra configuration on all BSD systems, for example, unless you're using something like Google Cloud, I guess, where the outgoing SMTP ports are blocked).

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2007/07/31/using-gmail-with-mutt-the-minimal-way/) there describe howto configure mutt for gmail.

Comment: When a link is provided as an answer, there's a relatively good chance the answer will eventually stop being useful if a site is moved. Consider trying to follow the directions yourself and distilling the commands it actually took.

Comment: Yes the world is not static. I could be that the question is not relevant anymore since mutt, gmail and the rest for the world has moved on since 2014. You can see my answer is given a few hour after the original poster posted his question - hopefully it was helpful at that point in time. If I was looking at this today, I would have put the link in a comment. BTW: the link is still valid - and also available in the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20181113143756/https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2007/07/31/using-gmail-with-mutt-the-minimal-way/